# How to solve the database challenge of new user-seller relationship vs old user-seller relations. DATABASE challenge

Tags: sql, mongodb, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation

Sorry for the unclear title, but here it goes.

a company owns several malls in several cites,  many users are logged in the system of the company, each user may purchases from a seller within a mall.
the purchase object might look like this :

```
{
user_id :     11,
mall_id :     12,
city_id :     13,
seller_id :   14,
country_id :  15,
product_id :  16,
brand_id :    17,
category_id : 18
......
}
```

the management wants to know how many:
users purchased products for the first time within a period (ie this month);

users purchased products from sellers for the first time

users purchased from malls for the first time

users purchased from cites for the first time

users purchased from sellers in a country for the first time

users purchased from a category from a mall from a brand for the first time.

and this goes on with any combinations that are possible...
my question is:
**Is there a name for this challenge in database science?

Are there sources for further readings?

And what are your suggestions to structure my data?**
I know about mongo [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/?_ga=2.243492229.1067511114.1665165004-1622819569.1664955413#-group--aggregation-) stage and [stringFacet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/facet-tutorial/) and I do not think they solve my problem, what do you think?

Comment: Hi - I’m not sure why you’ve described this as a “challenge” when all it is is a list of queries to run against your data, which seems perfectly straightforward. What “sources for further reading” are you looking for - how to query data? Is there a particular reason why you have chosen a NoSQL solution?

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you try to simulate the above and start writing the quries you will figure out that you have to scan the full db every time and for every doc.  I think it is a challenge to do it in a workable way, what we are looking to find is the new links between a combined select set of the above keys

Comment: If you have any suggestions in SQL , you are welcome

Comment: (I will admit my bias as I don't know NoSQL), if you had this data in a standard relational table then running the queries you want would be straightforward. If you had a large volume of data (and what you have talked about is only a small part of your overall dataset and reporting requirements) then I would build a proper reporting solution (data warehouse with star schemas)